# How do I collect System Hardware Information using my website

Tags: javascript, hardware

I want to be able to collect information like :

- Type of Laptop/PC : Make or Model ?
- Type of OS along with CPU and RAM
  amount ?
- If a special keyboard is being used then what is the model.

Is there any way to do this using JavaScript or any script that I can run in a browser?
(Chrome and Firefox not IE).

Answer (score 0):

Using the Javascript `navigator` object you can get an OS and browser version (this can be easily spoofed by a lot of browsers though). Unfortunately for anything more in depth you will need something running client side.